# Ignore CRC errors

Tags: batch-file, command-line, winzip

Software: Winzip Pro V19.0 64 bit

I'm using a process to combined split zip files into one. but there is a corrupt file in one of the split zip files. How do I ignore that corrupt file.
`"C:\Program Files\WinZip\wzzip" -yfs "C:\temp\Photos.zip"`
The error i'm getting in the command prompt is:

```
Some data in your Zip file is damaged - CRC check failed.
(select [o]k)
```

How do invoke the o in my script?

Comment: Does it wait for an input? If so you could probably use `echo o | yourCommand`

Comment: Yes it does wait.